# How to merge two dataframes for updating older one with new one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am sorry for being a noob but I can't find a solution for my problem with hours of search.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('df1.xlsx')
df1.set_index('time')
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_excel('df2.xlsx')
df2.set_index('time')
print(df2)

new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,how='outer')
print(new_df)

df1
   time  bought
0     1       0
1     2       0
2     3       0
3     4       0
4     5       1

df2
   time  bought
0     3       0
1     4       0
2     5       0
3     6       0
4     7       0

new_df
   time  bought
0     1       0
1     2       0
2     3       0
3     4       0
4     5       1
5     5       0
6     6       0
7     7       0
```

What I want is

1. updating `df1`(existing data) with `df2`(new data feed). when it comes to **bought** value, `df1` data should comes first
2. the `new_df` should have all unique **time** values from `df1`, `df2` without duplicates

I tried every method I found but no one made my desired outcome or created unnecessary duplicates as above.(two rows with **time** value of 5)
merge method created _x _y suffixes or duplicates

join() didn't work as well.

What I desire should look like:

```
new_df
   time  bought
0     1       0
1     2       0
2     3       0
3     4       0
4     5       1
5     6       0
6     7       0
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

if you perform the join as you have done all you need to do is remove the duplicate rows keeping only the more resent data,
`drop_duplicates()` take the kwarg `subset` which takes a list of columns and `keep` which sets which row to keep if there are duplicates
in this case we only need to check for duplicates in the `time` column and wee keep the first column

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('df1.xlsx')
df1.set_index('time')
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_excel('df2.xlsx')
df2.set_index('time')
print(df2)

new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,how='outer')
new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['time'], keep='first')
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   time  bought
0     1       0
1     2       0
2     3       0
3     4       0
4     5       1
5     6       0
6     7       0
```